# Errorchart.toURLString() in charts4j

Tags: java, swing, charts4j

I have a project, which need use chart from charts4j. I tried to compile this [source code](https://code.google.com/p/charts4j/source/browse/tags/v1.2/example/com/googlecode/charts4j/SwingExample.java#46) but it got this error..

> "javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't get input stream from URL!"

and this error at here:

`JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new URL(urlString))));`

I don't know why there is error..

Comment: This doesn't sound like a compilation error, but a run time error, which probably points to a invalid `urlString` value

Comment: Have compiled and run the code, it seems to work fine for me

Comment: urlString is a url string in charts4j library and i can't change it

Comment: it's not work for me.

Comment: charts4j creates a image on google's servers, nice, which is then downloaded and displayed an image.  So, if you have a firewall or some other blockage which prevents you computer from connecting to these services, you won't be able to download the image.  Equally, the connection code drop out/time out for some reason or the URL may become invalid after a period of time.  I don't think it's an issue with the code (although I would print the result of `chart.toURLString()` to the console and try pasting it into a browser).  It's also possible that the image might not be ready for download

Comment: yeah,I got it. it' firewall and i turn off it. Thank you so much bro